# iOS: from one app, how to open other installed app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to open another app from my app? If my app has advertisement for another app, and that app is installed on device as well, is there a way to open that app from my app?

Thanks

update:
looks like you need to know the scheme of the app, in order to launch it, but you cannot just lunch the app without any scheme and URL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use a concept known as URL schemes:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice tutorial on Using [Custom URL Scheme](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) in iOS

As in the tutorial, you should parse the URL parameters and store them to use in the app in this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
  // Do something with the url here
}
```

Here are a few examples …

```
myapp://

myapp://some/path/here

myapp://?foo=1&amp;bar=2

myapp://some/path/here?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use URL scheme for open another app. see this [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899).And here is the [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/).

Comment: have you tried it. is it solved?

Answer (score 0):

its just example to open to-do list in iPhone use following

Specify the app name and content you want to open, here "todolist://" is app name while remaining is content to open
 @"todolist://www.acme.com?Quarterly%20Report#200806231300"

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"todolist://www.acme.com?Quarterly%20Report#200806231300"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

if you still dont find right, refer apple documentation section (Communicating with Other Apps) for it 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html